# How to insert value into constructor that is obtained from authorization header

Tags: web-services, dependency-injection, constructor, asp.net-core-3.1

The service i'm writing looks like this:

```
services.AddScoped<a,b>();
...
public interface a

public class b:a
{
   private readonly someDB db;
   public b(someDB db)
   {
      this.db = db;
   }
}
```

what i'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
public class b:a
{
   private readonly someDB db;
   private readonly type t;
   public b(someDB db, type t)
   {
      this.db = db;
      this.t= t;
   }
}
```

the problem is the someType value is retrieved from request. How do i inject this value into constructor ?
For simplicity's sake let's consider *type* being *bool*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in a request then it wont be available at the time the constructor is invoked by the DI container.

However, you can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and extract the header information in a member accessed during the scope of a request.

```
public class b : a {
    private readonly someDB db;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public b(someDB db, IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
        this.db = db;
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    public void SomeMemberThatUsesT() {
        var request = accessor.HttpContext.Request;
        //extract desired header data
    }
}
```